# Why Scrapy's design default can only run a spider

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm new in python.I want to use Scrapy crawling message in internet and I design two spiders ,but I just can run one spider.Although I've solved this problem through find a way from internet,but once one spider stop all of my spiders stop ,how can I run spiders mutual independence

Comment: Please provide your code and read the help on [ask] a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings    
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
for each_spider in yourspiderslist:
    process.crawl(each_spider)
process.start()
```

Comment: thanks very much,but I want to run spiders mutual independence like my two spiders run in two thread,I've tried this way and when I let a spider enter the dead cycle ,all my spider stop

Answer (score 0):

For such purpose, you might want to use e.g. [Scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which lets you schedule multiple spiders to run in parallel. If you have even more demanding use cases, you can build your own scraping infrastructure involving setting up multiple Scrapyd servers.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out one direction for me,thanks very much